# Social network filtering for specific topic

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design

I created and operate a social network for meeting new people.  As a result of the recent FOSTA legislation, it’s imperative that I implement an automated system to prevent users from posting advertisements relating to prostitution. I do not have much expierence with AI/Machine learning.  What library, algorithm, method should I look into to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to ai.se.. Don't you think you should narrow down some algorithms and then ask which will be the best for your problem.

Comment: please elaborate on the type of content your social media website allows? do you need your 'algorithm' to look into only text data or do you need to look into image data as well? are videos allowed on your social media website?

Comment: Machine learning-Supervised learning algorithm can do better.